# The dropdown button is not working in Bootstrap

Tags: css, menu

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu using bootstrap. I simply copied the following code from the Bootstrap documentation. Would you please tell me what the wrong is with my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


  <title>Buttons</title>
</head>
<body>
  

   <!-- DROPDOWN BUTTONS -->
   <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">2</button>
  
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</
```

html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what [the bootstrap site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/#overview) has said, you need to add one third-party library.

you must load this before bootstrap js.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```